# calculation of matrix-based transformation of differential entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Consider the matrix transformation $\mathbf{Y=AX}$, where $\mathbf Y$, $\mathbf A$, and $\mathbf X$ are all matrices. If $\mathbf A$ is a determinant and square matrix we know the differential entropy satisfying
$$h(\mathbf Y)=h(\mathbf X)+\log\det(\mathbf A).$$

What if determinant matrix $\mathbf A$ is not square?

Comment: Hint: the interesting case is when $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$ is fat (i.e., $k < d$) and full row rank (why?). In this case, first try to deal with $A$ that are rectangular-diagonal. This can be generalised by working with the singular value decomposition of $A$.